# How to remember the users session on page refresh?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, local-storage, ember-cli

Lately, I've been following http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/client-side-authentication-part-2 as a guide to setup authentication on my Ember CLI app. I also have a seperate API (Backed by Rails), which my Ember CLI app communicates with.

The Ember cast encourages the use of storing auth data in localstorage to remember the users session when he refreshes the page.

Which got me thinking. Since localtorage can be accessed by the client, and eventually modified. Why does ember-cli suggest such practices? Isn't this unsafe?

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/04/13/towards-more-secure-client-side-data-storage/ has a good explanation why localstorage can become an issue with sensitive data.

Or am I missing the point?

If localstorage is not the way to go, then what strategies can I look into?

Comment: What's in auth data? Cause I am lazy to watch the whole screencast. If it's something returned from the backend like an API token, it goes without saying that it should be HMAC-ed in the backend.

Comment: OK so the token is stored in local storage. But what if I need to display the users (associated with the token) full name, user id. Should these also be stored in local storage? Or should I execute an API request against the token, and return the user object in json?